# Multiple MySql Insert & Updates not running as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to Insert information into a table and update two rows in another table (in the same database) in one string. I was under the impression you could do this quite simply by adding a semi-colon after each attempt and it would action them all individually within the same string.

I cannot think of any other way to achieve the desired effect of inserting the data in the  'games' table and updating the data in the two unique rows in the 'players' table simultaneously.

Here's my code...

```
<?php

include_once('database-details.php');

$winner         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['winner']);
$loser              = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['loser']);
$balled         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['balled']);
$fixtures           = 'games';
$table              = 'players';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$fixtures` "
    . "(`id`, `winner`, `loser`, `balled`) VALUES "
    . "(NULL, '$winner', '$loser', '$balled') ;"
    . "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, wins = wins + 1, balled = balled + $balled WHERE id = $winner ;"
    . "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, losses = losses + 1, balled = balled - $balled WHERE id = $loser";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

$response = (object)array('status' => 'error');

if($result){
    $response = (object)array(
        'status'    => 'ok',
        'id'        => $db->insert_id,
    );
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Footnote...
The form is submitted with ajax to then update the content on the front end. I can confirm that the submission works fine when there is only one of the requests I have tested with all three submitting indiviually and each worked fine. It only breaks when I combine them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: From reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php it seems that you should use mysqli_multi_query()

Comment: Just tried the link you've provided and it seems to have done the trick! Thank you for providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you HAVE to do the update queries in the same query?

Also no point having

```
$response = (object)array('status' => 'error');

if($result){
```

Because you have already stopped script execution on the line above

```
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
```

Maybe Try:

```
<?php

include_once('database-details.php');

$winner         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['winner']);
$loser              = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['loser']);
$balled         = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['balled']);
$fixtures           = 'games';
$table              = 'players';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$fixtures` "
    . "(`id`, `winner`, `loser`, `balled`) VALUES "
    . "(NULL, '$winner', '$loser', '$balled') ;"

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
else{
    $insertid = $db->insert_id
    $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, wins = wins + 1, balled = balled + $balled WHERE id = $winner ;"
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, losses = losses + 1, balled = balled - $balled WHERE id = $loser";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
    $response = (object)array(
        'status'    => 'ok',
        'id'        => $insertid ,
    );
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Depending on your $db class your value of insert_id may be not what you expect if you are running multiple sql statements in the one query.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a concurrency problem. You may want to use to turn autocommit to off, and use mysqli_begin_transaction() to set a block, execute your queries and mysqli_commit() to process the block.

Something like:

```
    mysqli_autocommit($db, FALSE);
    mysqli_begin_transaction();
    //now call query() as many times as needed
    mysqli_commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your rapid responses. In the end the link @AR provided for mysqli_multi_query() did the trick. Here's how it looks now (if anyones interested)...

```
<?php

include_once('database-details.php');

$winner    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['winner']);
$loser     = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['loser']);
$balled    = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['balled']);
$fixtures  = 'games';
$table     = 'players';

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$fixtures` "
    . "(`id`, `winner`, `loser`, `balled`) VALUES "
    . "(NULL, '$winner', '$loser', '$balled') ;"
    . "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, wins = wins + 1, balled = balled + $balled WHERE id = $winner ;"
    . "UPDATE `$table` SET apps = apps + 1, losses = losses + 1, balled = balled + $balled WHERE id = $loser";

if (!$db->multi_query($sql)) {
    echo "Multi query failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
}

do {
    if ($result = $db->store_result()) {
        $response = (object)array(
            'status'    => 'ok'
        );
        $result->free();
    }
} while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

PS - Thanks @Hadyn Dickson for the advice on the queries.